# Complex filtering on Kendo Datasources

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have some Kendo Grid's and Scheduler's and I want to apply a complex filter like ((A or B or C) and (D or E)). If the filter is simple, like (A or B or C), everything ok, but with the first mentioned complex type of filter, I'm not able to achieve it.

Here's what I have tried:

```
function filterByTechnicalAndStatus() {
    var allFilters = [];
    var technicalFilters = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
    var statusFilters = { logic: "or", filters: [] };
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    var userGrid = $("#userGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var selectedUsers = userGrid.select();
    if (selectedUsers.length != 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedUsers.length; i++) {
            var code = userGrid.dataItem(selectedUsers[i]).Code;
            technicalFilters.filters.push({ field: "Technical", operator: "eq", value: code });
        }
    }
    if ($('#chk_PL').prop('checked')) {
        statusFilters.filters.push({ field: "InspectionStatusCode", operator: "eq", value: "PL" });
    }
    if ($('#chk_OPEN').prop('checked')) {
        statusFilters.filters.push({ field: "InspectionStatusCode", operator: "eq", value: "OPEN" });
    }
    if ($('#chk_EXEC').prop('checked');) {
        statusFilters.filters.push({ field: "InspectionStatusCode", operator: "eq", value: "EXEC" });
    }

    allFilters.push(statusFilters);
    allFilters.push(technicalFilters);

    scheduler.dataSource.filter(
        [
            { "logic": "or",
                "filters": [
                            { "field": "InspectionStatusCode", "operator": "eq", "value": "PL" },
                            { "field": "InspectionStatusCode", "operator": "eq", "value": "OPEN" }
                            ]
            },
            { "logic": "or",
                "filters": [
                            { "field": "Technical", "operator": "eq", "value": "PSOARES" },
                            { "field": "Technical", "operator": "eq", "value": "ASOARES" }
                            ]
            }
        ]
    );
    //scheduler.dataSource.filter(allFilters);
    }
```

At the end of the above function, I've got `scheduler.dataSource.filter` set "manually" and just below a commented line. The manual setting works as expected: however, I don't want to do that "manually", obviously.

The commented line is what I expected to work fine but breaks and opens the `kendo.all.min.js` file with a syntax error alert.

I have found [this](http://www.telerik.com/forums/multiple-filters-on-datasource) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/valchev/MG89G/) but wasn't able to overcome my problem. How can I set a complex filter other than "manually"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing:

```
ds.filter([
    {
        "logic":"and",
        "filters":[
            {
                "logic":"or",
                "filters":[
                    // Your A condition
                    { "field": "InspectionStatusCode", "operator": "eq", "value": "PL" },
                    // Your B condition
                    { "field": "InspectionStatusCode", "operator": "eq", "value": "OPEN" }
                    {
                        // Your C condition
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "logic":"or",
                "filters":[
                    {
                        // Your D condition
                    },
                    {
                        // Your E condition
                    }
               ]
            }
        ]
    }
]);
```

I.e. Write a first filter with login "AND" which contains two filters. Each of these filters have and "OR" filter with the conditions that you want.

Remember that:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you write an example of what I could have in one of the commented lines like `Your A condition`? The conditions to set the filters can be seen in the code inside the question, that's how I build the two subfilters

Comment: I tried putting the if conditions where you have `// Your A condition` but the IDE shows errors in the code: `"filters": [
                            if (chk_pl) {
           { "field": "InspectionStatusCode", "operator": "eq", "value": "PL" }
                            },`

Comment: But you cannot include code. Only and - or different filter confitions

Comment: But I want to define the filters based on previous checks, and instead of writing `{ "field": "InspectionStatusCode", "operator": "eq", "value": "PL" }` the number of times needed, I want to to pass an array with these lines. If you analyze my code, you can see I create two subfilters (arrays) that are filled with what I need. I just want to pass them into the `dataSource.filter`

Comment: If you want to add new restrictions means that you are and'ing them. You define at top level an and with one element in filter array and when needed you push in filters vector the new restrictions

Comment: Yes, I know that. I'm able to pass an array for simple filtering like `scheduler.dataSource.filter(allFilters);` if the `allFilters` variable is built via push something like `.push({ field: "InspectionStatusCode", operator: "eq", value: "PL" });` - This works great. But I'm not able to build a complex logic inside the array I pass as parameter for the `datasource.filter`, that's my issue. Could you help with that? Because "manually" I am able to pass the complex filters, I think it's a matter of building the parameter array correctly.

Comment: Check this example of building complex filter: http://dojo.telerik.com/@OnaBai/uSolu

Comment: It works perfectly now. Many thanks OnaBai, once again you showed your large Kendo UI skill set, your answer is correct (and upvoted too!)

Comment: The only _tricky_ thing that I've seen is that you cannot have two conditions where one is `and` and the `filters` array is empty (for the `or` there is no problem having filters empty). É um prazer poder ajudar.

Comment: Once again, muito obrigado OnaBai